# Sortin apache log with Python

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7

For example I have this simple apache log:

```
192.168.1.1 GET /index.php
192.168.1.1 GET /pilt.png
192.168.1.1 GET /index.php
192.168.1.5 GET /index.php
192.168.1.5 GET /pilt.png
192.168.1.7 GET /index.php
192.168.1.7 GET /index.php
192.168.1.7 GET /index.php
192.168.1.7 GET /kaust/index.php
192.168.1.7 GET /index.php
```

How would I write a Python code to sort it out that all the similar IP addresses are together and counted how much IP addresses are there

```
w = open("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\test.txt","r")

for i in w:
  log=i.split(' ')
  print log[0]
w.close()
```

Have tried so much, but can't write the code further.

Thank you!

Comment: you want both functionality that both IP address are sorted and all the unique IP address. Right??

Comment: Can you show us what output exactly you want?

Comment: it's a dictionary thing I guess
    192.168.1.1 : 3
     192.168.1.5 : 2
and so forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it will be done :

```
x = open('PATH_TO_FILE').read()

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
x = x.split('\n')
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] = x[i].split(' ')

j = 0

for elt, items in groupby(x, itemgetter(0)):
    j += 1
    k = 0
    print elt, items
    for i in items:
        k += 1
        print i
    print 'Total count for IP ',i[0],' is :',k

print 'Total unique IP address are : ',j
```

Comment: no using python 2.7 only, but did you remove the read() from it??

Comment: yes my bad.... but I want count like after every repeating IP. So it's like a dictionary

Comment: changed it please verify.

Comment: so I have to import other libraries, no basic way to do it?

Comment: other wise if you want to do all by yourself, it will be quite lenghty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultdict(int)` for your purpose :

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(int)
w = open("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\test.txt", "r")
for line in w:
    ip = line.split(' ')[0]
    my_dict[ip]+=1

my_dict  # defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'192.168.1.7': 5, '192.168.1.1': 3, '192.168.1.5': 2})
```